# Django Rest Framework list_route and queryset on tree structure

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-mptt

Trying to display hierarchy of categories through DRF serializer and it fails

```
GET /api/mobile/v1/categories/tree/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c6b6c0e4-18f3-f8c4-1d77-75fc21a6a431
```

builtins.AttributeError

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `id` on serializer `CategoryTreeSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `TreeQuerySet` instance. Original exception text was: 'TreeQuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'.
```

**Viewset**

```
class CategoryViewSet(
        mixins.ListModelMixin,
        viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    """Category view set.

    List model viewset for ``Category`` model.

    """
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    pagination_class = None

    @decorators.list_route(methods=['get'])
    def tree(self, *args, **kwargs):

        categories = Category.objects.filter(parent=None).all()
        serializer = CategoryTreeSerializer(categories)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=serializer.data
```

**My Model**

```
class Category(MPTTModel):

    id = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        primary_key=True,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name=_('ID'),
        help_text=_('Forsquare ID of the category.'),
    )
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        'self',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='children',
        db_index=True,
        verbose_name=_('Parent category'),
        help_text=_('Parent category.'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    plural_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name=_('Plural name')
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Category')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Categories')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Serializer**

```
class CategoryTreeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Category serializer.

    Serializer for ``Category`` model. Excludes fields specified for MPTT.

    """
    children = serializers.ListField(child=RecursiveField())

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'plural_name', 'children',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok worked after the following changes

```
class CategoryViewSet(
        mixins.ListModelMixin,
        UserFavoritesMixin,
        viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    """Category view set.

    List model viewset for ``Category`` model.

    """
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    pagination_class = None

    @decorators.list_route(methods=['get'])
    def tree(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        """
        categories = Category.objects.filter(level=0).all()
        serializer = CategoryTreeSerializer(categories, many=True)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=serializer.data)


class CategoryTreeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Category serializer.

    Serializer for ``Category`` model. Excludes fields specified for MPTT.

    """
    children = RecursiveField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'plural_name', 'children',)
```